# Is it possible to maintain a background image's aspect ratio when resized within a responsive layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

I am working on building an application to customize a guitar. To cut down on load time, I created a type of sprite sheet with the guitar bodies and all the parts all in one or two images. In the code block I am working on below, a div tag, is being styled.

For this image, the original proportions are 2870 pixels width by 1700 pixels height. In the example below, the image being "cropped out" or shown by the background image property is 1001 pixels width by 326 pixels height.

I tried using percentages but could not figure out how to maintain proportions when changing the width of the div tag for a responsive layout.

```
#camila_template_wpr {
    background-image: url(../img/jpg_sprite.jpg);
    background-position: 0% 23.7%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 524%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 324px;
    max-width: 1001px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: When I use the max-width property the height is unresponsive and the background image does not scale with the width.

Comment: Dave, you suggested edits to my code, but you're changing the % value used in the padding. Why are you changing that? My explanation of "59.2% is the height's percentage of the width" is no longer relevant if you change the % value, then there is no explanation in my post as to how to get the % value. I'd like to know how you got the new padding %.

Comment: I looked at this again and I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. The width of the "cropped out" a.k.a. background image section is 1001 pixel width by 326 pixel height. 326 divided by 1001 is .325674, so my current logic was the width is 32.567% of the height. Therefor the bottom padding should be 32.567%. I'm not sure where I got 30.895% but it did look good on a preview because it was close to the calculated 32.567%.

I'm still having an issue with the image skewing once the max-width reaches 1001 pixels. The height continues to grow.

Comment: ok yeah your math is right. re: the image skewing, this has to do with the `background-size` property. I would need to see your complete code with a working image and whatever your expected behavior is to help.

Comment: Is that what GitHub is for? A GitHub tutorial is on my to do list. I fixed the skewing by setting the max-width to 100% and wrapping the div in another div that has a max width of 1001 pixels. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Github is a version control repo for git repos. np!

Answer (score 0):

Try `height: 0; padding-bottom: 30.895%; 30.895% is the height's percentage of the width.

```css
#camila_template_wpr {
background-image: url(../img/jpg_sprite.jpg);
background-position: 0% 23.7%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 286.713% 524%;
display: block;
margin:  0 auto;
height: 0px;
max-width: 1001px;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 32.567%;
}
```

```html
<div id="camila_template_wpr"></div>
```